# zf2 phpunit scheme routes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

We're using ZF2 for an web-application and want to test it with phpunit (v4.8.9). Within this application we've got a scheme-route, to be able to switch between http/https-context (Doesnt matter why...). The route looks like this:

```
'http' => array(
    'type' => 'Scheme',
    'options' => array(
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'defaults' => array(
            'http' => true
        )
    ),
    'child_routes' => array(
        'search' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/search[/:keyword[/:page]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'page' => '[1-9]+[0-9]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => SearchController::class,
                    'action'        => 'search',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'https' => array(
    'type' => 'Scheme',
    'options' => array(
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'defaults' => array(
            'https' => true
        )
    ),
    'child_routes' => array(
        'search' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/search[/:keyword[/:page]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'page' => '[1-9]+[0-9]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => SearchController::class,
                    'action'        => 'search',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

The class of the test looks like this:

```
class SearchControllerTest extends SynHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig($this->getCurrentBootstrap()->getApplicationConfig());
        parent::setUp();
        $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
    }

    public function testSearchActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/search');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertControllerName(SearchController::class);
        $this->assertControllerClass('SearchController');
        $this->assertActionName('search');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('search');
    }
}
```

*FYI:*
The "SynHttpControllerTestCase" is an extension from the original AbstractHttpControllerTestCase which comes with Zend-Test. It's modified to get the right bootstrap-file in our tests.

If we're running the tests, this error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getParam() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\git\xxx\vendor\zendframework\zend-test\src\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractControllerTestCase.php on line 563

We looked into the AbstractControllerTestCase and this line is throwing the error:

```
$routeMatch = $this->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
```

Because the $routeMatch-Object is empty.
We've some other controllers and tests within our application, they're all fine and not affected from this problem, cause the routes to these controllers arent scheme-routes.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this? In advance: we're not able to use static https-routes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a lot of official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html#your-first-controller-test) on how to write a proper controller test. In your `setUp` method you need to attach a `Router` instance to a `RouteMatch` instance which you attach to a `MvcEvent` in the controller.

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
    $this->controller = new IndexController();
    $this->request    = new Request();
    $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
    $this->event      = new MvcEvent();
    $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
    $routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
    $router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);

    $this->event->setRouter($router);
    $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
    $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
    $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
}
```

Then you can call `dispatch`.

### UPDATE

Can you not set your route match object like this:

```
$routeParams  = array('controller' => 'search', 'action' => 'search');
$routeMatch   = new RouteMatch($routeParams);
$routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
$router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);

$event        = new MvcEvent();
$event->setRouter($router);
$event->setRouteMatch($routeMatch);

$this->getApplication()->setMvcEvent($event);
```

Comment: Yes your're right. But i think i forgot to say, that this is an integrationtest. So there is some other logic, which needs to be called from this test. For example there is an listener which have to be fired and so on. So, your example doesnt fits our needs.

For a better understanding, take a look here:
[link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#your-first-controller-test)

Comment: @RonnyLindner I updated my answer, I think the solution lies very much in the line of my previous answer. Only you have to set the `RouteMatch` corresponding to the route you want to test.